# i want to know about can i read two json files in one route?

Tags: javascript, node.js

Students.JSON

```
{
    "Students" : [
        {"ID" : "1" ,
         "Name" : "janaka",
         "Grade" : "A"
        },
        {"ID" : "2" ,
         "Name" : "Darshana",
         "Grade" : "B"
```

parent.JSON

```
{
"parents" : [
    {"pID" : "1" ,
     "pName" : "janaka ravindra"
    },
    {"pID" : "2" ,
     "pName" : "Darshana disanayaka"
```

### There are two route in one .JS file....

```
app.get('/students/:id',function(req ,res){
fs.readFile( __dirname + "/" + "Students_details.json", 'utf8',function(err,data){

        //in here i code completly i got ID,Name,Grade according to the requested id. there is know question to me. but Look next route.....
  }
}
```

### Here is my next route

```
    app.get('/getFullStudentDetails/:id',function(req , res){
        fs.readFile(__dirname + "/" + "parent.json", 'utf8',function(err,data){
        fs.readFile( __dirname + "/" + "Students_details.json", 'utf8',function(err,data){

           var content = JSON.parse(data); //convert to the JSON herevar 
           st_array = content.Students; // get "Student array to new variable

     });
   });
});
```

- Above i try to read two JSON files in one route but i dont know that way is right or wrong. i want to explanation about that also.
- As well as is that way wrong i want to know how to do that correctly.
- In Top of the question i have mention the arrays also if you want.
- Finely i will explain the process here like this what i am going to do....
- when i run this route "'/students/:id'" i received "ID,Name,Grade".
  That's clear. But when i run "/getFullStudentDetails/:id" this route
  i want to "Students.JSON" details (ID,Name,Grade) + "parent.JSON
  (pName).
- pName is not want to display because all details display by id that i entered (ID==pID)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

can you not just require them like this?

```
const obj1 = require("parent.json");
const obj2 = require("Students_details.json");
```

Answer (score 0):

Try **require** :

```
const json1 = require("parent.json"); 
const json2 =require("Students_details.json");
```